# Как построить топ?

Tags: formula, php, wordpress

Добрый день!

Дано: сайт на WordPress.

Задача: сделать топ по формуле Байеса [(как на кинопоиске в низу страницы)](http://www.kinopoisk.ru/top/). Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда и как вставляются такие вещи и как они работают.

Спасибо большое за ваше время!

Answer (score 1):

Делаем выборку из БД требуемых данных по фильмам, и подставляем в формулу:
(V/(V+M))*R+((M/V+M)*C)

```
V –  количество голосов за фильм
M –  порог голосов, необходимый для участия в рейтинге Топ-250 (сейчас: 500)
R –  среднее арифметическое всех голосов за фильм
С –  среднее значение рейтинга всех фильмов (сейчас: 7.2712)
```

Comment: это понятно.
я не очень понимаю куда вставить эту формулу, куда ее прописать что бы она работала и делала то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Поделюсь мнением, если еще необходимо:

1. Заводим необходимые дополнительные поля в постах фильмов.
2. Реализуем обновление дополнительного поля при добавлении голоса пользователем.

3.1. Либо производим расчет рейтинга фильма налету при добавлении очередного голоса.

3.2. Либо рассчитываем рейтинг фильма при выборке и формировании общего рейтинга.

4. Создаем отдельный шаблон страницы (page-rating.php), либо делаем отдельный шаблон категории рейтинга.
5. Делаем выборку с помощью цикла, получаем мета поля, отсеиваем налету "Порог голосов".
6. Далее рассчитываем остальные формулы и по результатам расчета делаем сортировку списка.

Answer (score 0):

Промежуточные цифры: число голосов за фильм и среднее арифметическое реально просчитывать "на лету" при голосовании. Хранить факты голосов в отдельной таблице Голоса плюс в Фильмах поля под среднее и количество. То есть клик в голосовании это один INSERT и один UPDATE.

Конечную формулу можно расчитывать время от времени по расписанию и записывать в отдельную итоговую таблицу Топ.

Нет никакой жгучей необходимости передвигать позиции рейтинга после каждого голоса. На больших цифрах вклад одного конкретного клика незначителен.